# Presto Produce JSON results

Tags: sql, json, presto, trino

I have a json table which was created by

```
CREATE TABLE `normaldata_source`(
  `column1` int, 
  `column2` string, 
  `column3` struct<column4:string>)
```

A sample data is:

```
{
  "column1": 9,
  "column2": "Z",
  "column3": {
    "column4": "Y"
  }
}
```

If I do

```
SELECT column3
FROM normaldata_source
```

it will produce a result `{column4=y}`. However, I want it to be in json form `{"column4": "y"}`

Is this possible?

*Edit This query gives me the following result:

```
SELECT CAST(column3 AS JSON) as column3_json
FROM normaldata_source
```

[image: result]

Comment: There are some workaround (e.g. building string with format function), support for casting to json with field names is ongoing in https://github.com/trinodb/trino/pull/3613.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, my real object has many fields and is nested, so building the string with format function will be quite tedious. I was hoping there there would be an easier way. The link is for trino, but is that the same thing as presto?

Comment: Yes, https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html is the relevant blog post.

Answer (score 4):

As of [Trino 357 (formerly known as Presto SQL)](https://trino.io/docs/current/release/release-357.html), you can now cast a `row` to `JSON` and it will preserve the column names:

```sql
WITH normaldata_source(column1, column2, column3) AS (
    VALUES (9, 'Z', cast(row('Y') as row(column4 varchar)))
)
SELECT cast(column3 as json) 
FROM normaldata_source
```

=>

```
      _col0
-----------------
 {"column4":"Y"}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same problem and was thoroughly stumped on how to proceed in light of deep compositional nesting/structs. I'm using Athena (managed Presto w/ Hive Connector from AWS). In the end, I worked around it by doing a CTAS (create table as select) where I selected the complex column I wanted, under the conditions I wanted) and wrote it to an external table with an underlying SerDe format of JSON. Then, via the HiveConnector's $path magic column (or by listing the files under the external table location), I obtain the resulting files and streamed out of those.

I know this isn't a direct answer to the question at hand - I believe we have to wait for https://github.com/trinodb/trino/pull/3613 in order to support arbitrary struct/array compositions -> json. But maybe this will help someone else who kind of assumed they'd be able to do this.

Although I originally saw this as an annoying workaround, I'm now starting to think it was the right call for my application anyway

Comment: Would it be possible to share a reproducible example of what you implemented? I'm totally stuck on this issue right now!